# How to List User or Role accessing S3 Private Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

What method to list IAM User or Role that accessing Private S3 Buckets in Single account.

Comment: Do you want to list all the roles that *can* access the bucket or do you want to know which roles *did* access the bucket? In the second case you need to have enabled the CloudTrail logging of the access logs and then sift through the logs. In the first case you are pretty much out of luck because you would need to parse all kind of IAM policies with complicated logic and syntax and will certainly miss something.

Comment: To know which roles did access the bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can activate logging on the Amazon S3 bucket.

See: [Logging requests using server access logging - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ServerLogs.html)

The logs include a field for **Requester**:

> The canonical user ID of the requester, or a - for unauthenticated requests. If the requester was an IAM user, this field returns **the requester's IAM user name** along with the AWS root account that the IAM user belongs to. This identifier is the same one used for access control purposes.

Comment: But make sure to monitor the cost of this - when we turned it on we were dealing with >40k€/month just for the access logs. Yes, this was for 100s of TB of data, billions of requests but still, keep the cost of this in mind.

Comment: May be we can use Athena to query the logs.

Comment: Can we use AWS CLI to get those information..?

Comment: The S3 Access Logs are text files stored in S3. There can be a large quantity of logs files, so they can be hard to process. The easiest way is to use Amazon Athena to query the S3 Access Logs. See: [Analyze S3 server access logs using Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/analyze-logs-athena/)